# How will I loop this java program with Question of "Do you want to Try Again?! [Yes/No]"?

Tags: java, loops

> I'm new on this java programming. And I need to make this program loop
>   the Question "Do you want to Try Again?! [Yes/No]" and loop it back to
>   "Enter any year:" question. How will I do that?

I hope you provided me with more elaborated answer or example to make this program work properly within today..

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class my_LeapYear {

public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter any year: ");
    int year = s.nextInt();
    boolean loop = true;
    while(loop == true)
{
    if (((year %4==0)&& (year %100 !=0))||(year %400==0))
    {
        System.out.println("Year "+year+" is a Leap Year");
        break;
    }
    else if ((year %100 == 0)&&(year %400 == 0))
{
} else {
        System.out.println("Year "+year+" is not a Leap Year");
        loop = false;
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Remove the `break`s.

Comment: feedback: use `while(loop)`  instead of `while(loop == true)`

Comment: Also read about java naming conventions. Class names go UpperCase in java, and you only use the "_" for SOME_CONSTANT.

Comment: Also note: indentation really matters. Be consistent about what you do. The **structure** of your loop/if is completely hidden from the reader, just because of inconsistent indentation of blocks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `if` statement that checks whether yes or no is entered , update the value of `loop` accordingly see below

```
   System.out.println("Do you want to Try Again")   
    String input = in.nextLine();
    if (input.equals("YES")){
        loop = true
    }
    else if (input.equals("NO")){
        loop=false
    }
```